# Get result from sql with ignore some numbers

Tags: php, mysql

In MySQL table, i have a row for user groups. in this row i have user group numbers.
i'm trying to get result from all usergroups except 0 and 5.

I tried with this code:

```
$sql = $db->query("
SELECT 
author FROM dle_photo_post where ug<'5' and moder ='0'
");
```

Problem is i don't know how i can ignore 0 and 5.

Comment: Make sure 0 and 5 is number or character .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
author FROM dle_photo_post where ug not in('5','0') and moder ='0'
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using : NOT ?

Refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html for further information.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT author FROM dle_photo_post where ug!=5 and ug!=0
```

Answer (score 1):

If `ug` is a single number then you should be able to do

```
SELECT
    author
FROM
    dle_photo_post
WHERE
    ug <> 5 AND ug <> 0
```

Answer (score 1):

try,

```
SELECT author 
FROM dle_photo_post 
where usergroups NOT IN (0, 5)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = $db->query("
SELECT 
author FROM dle_photo_post where ug not in('0','5')
");
```

Comment: @Alireza Welcome . Feel free to ask .!